# List network printers with oracle sql

Tags: c#, oracle, delphi

Is there way to list all printers on a domain? 
note:I can use delphi 4 or oracle 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to this article: [Tutorial: 
List network providers, domains, servers, drives, and printers in Delphi.](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3823.asp?SK=listview)

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to list the printers in the domain from Oracle.  However, even if you could, I'm not sure you'd want to.  Doing this from Oracle would give you results for the Oracle server's domain, not the client's, which in many cases will be different.